# How do you sort a dictionary by it's values and then sum these values up to a certain point?

Tags: julia

I was wondering what the best method would be to sort a dictionary of type Dict{String, Int} based on the value. I loop over a FASTQ file containing multiple sequence records, each record has a String as an identifier which serves as key and another string where i take the length from as the value of the key.

for example:

```
    testdict["ee0a"]=length("aatcg")
    testdict["002e4"]=length("aatcgtga")
    testdict["12-f9"]=length(aatcgtgacgtga")
```

In this case the key value pairs would be `"ee0a" => 5`, `"002e4" => 8`, and `"12-f9" => 13`.

What i want to do is sort these pairs from highest value to the lowest value, afterwhich i sum these values in a different untill a that variable passes a certain threshold. I then need to save the keys i used so i can use them later on.

Is it possible to use the sort() function or use a SortedDict to achieve this? I would imagine that if the sorting succeeded i could use a while loop to add my keys to a list and add my values into a  different variable untill it's greater than my threshold, and then use the list of keys to create a new dictionary with my selected key-value pairs.

However what would be the fastest way to do this? the FASTQ files i read in can contain multiple GB's worth of data so i'd love to create a sorted dictionary while reading in the file and select the records i want before doing anything else with the data.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is multiple GB's worth of data I would avoid storing them in the `Dict` in the first place. I think it is better to process the file sequentially and store the keys that meet your condition in a `PriorityQueue` from the `DataStructures.jl` package. Of course you can repeat the same procedure if you read the data from a dictionary in memory (simply source changes from disk file to the dictionary)

Here is a pseudocode of what you could consider (a full solution would depend on how you read your data which you did not specify).
Assume that you want to store elements until they execeed threshold kept in `THRESH` constant.

```
pq = PriorityQueue{String, Int}()
s = 0

while (there are more key-value pairs in source file)
    key, value = read(source file)
    # this check avoids adding a key-value pair for which we are sure that
    # it is not interesting
    if s <= THRESH || value > peek(pq)[2]
        enqueue!(pq, key, value)
        s += value
        # if we added something to the queue we have to check
        # if we should not drop smallest elements from it
        while s - peek(pq)[2] > THRESH
            s -= dequeue!(pq)[2]
        end
    end
end
```

After this process `pq` will hold only key-value pairs you are interested in. The key benefit of this approach is that you never need to store whole data in RAM. At any point in time you only store the key-value pairs that would be selected at this stage of processing of the data.

Observe that this process does not give you an easily predictable result because several keys might have the same value. And if this value would be on a cutoff border you do not know which ones would be retained (however, you did not specify what you want to do in this special case - if you would specify the requirement for this case the algorithm should be updated a bit).

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory to hold at least one or two full Dicts of the required size, you can use an inverted Dict with the length as key and an array of the old keys as values, to avoid losing data with a duplicate length value as a same key.

I think that the code below is then what your question was leading toward:

```
d1 = Dict("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 2, "e" => 1, "f" =>5)

d2 = Dict()
for (k, v) in d1
    d2[v] = haskey(d2, v) ? push!(d2[v], k) : [k]
end

println(d1)
println(d2)

for k in sort(collect(keys(d2)))
    print("$k, $(d2[k]);  ")
    # here can delete keys under a threshold to speed further processing
end
```

If you don't have enough memory to hold an entire Dict, you may benefit 
from first putting the data into a SQL database like SQLite and then doing 
queries instead of modifying a Dict in memory. In that case, one column 
of the table will be the data, and you would add a column for the data length 
to the SQLite table. Or you can use a PriorityQueue as in the answer above.